# Kivrei Tanaim and Amoraim

Tags: eretz-yisrael, historical-figures, funeral-burial-levaya, cemetery-grave, oral-torah

How do we know for certain where in Israel Tanaim and Amoraim are buried if we've been exiled for so long?

Comment: Not everyone has been exiled. Moreover most of those graves date from after the exile began

Comment: Archeology can be quite accurate!

Comment: How do you know for certain that we know for certain?

Comment: Many of these identifications are based on the claims of mystics who lived a millennium or more after the people whose graves they supposedly identified. It is not based on tradition as the question insinuates.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I see no such insinuation. On the contrary, your claim that it's based on mystics' work sounds like the kernel of an answer post. Want to post one?

Comment: @meva I really don't think insinuate is the correct word here

Comment: @msh210 Why is tagged oral-Torah then, if nothing else.

Comment: I didn't intend the negative connotation. 'implies' would've worked, except I thought the implication wasn't quite strong enough to warrant the verb. @DoubleAA

Answer (score 1):

Many locations were provided by Ariza"l. See Shivchey HoAri on this topic.

See examples [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9553&st=&pgnum=10) and [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9553&st=&pgnum=11).